# Min item is not the first when ordered by

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Here is a basic example:

```
CREATE TABLE samuel(id varchar(1), field varchar(1));
INSERT INTO samuel VALUES ('1', ' ');
INSERT INTO samuel VALUES ('2', '&');
```

When doing `SELECT id, field, DUMP(field) FROM samuel order by field;` with Oracle 11.2.0.4.0, I get:

| ID | FIELD | DUMP |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | & | Typ=1 Len=1: 38 |
| 1 |  | Typ=1 Len=1: 32 |

But when doing `select id from samuel where field=(select min(field) from samuel);` I get **1**!

Here are the NLS settings:

| PARAMETER | VALUE |
| --- | --- |
| NLS_LANGUAGE | FRENCH |
| NLS_TERRITORY | FRANCE |
| NLS_CURRENCY | € |
| NLS_ISO_CURRENCY | FRANCE |
| NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS | , |
| NLS_CALENDAR | GREGORIAN |
| NLS_DATE_FORMAT | DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS |
| NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE | FRENCH |
| NLS_SORT | FRENCH |
| NLS_TIME_FORMAT | HH24:MI:SSXFF |
| NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT | DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SSXFF |
| NLS_TIME_TZ_FORMAT | HH24:MI:SSXFF TZR |
| NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT | DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SSXFF TZR |
| NLS_DUAL_CURRENCY | € |
| NLS_COMP | BINARY |
| NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS | BYTE |
| NLS_NCHAR_CONV_EXCP | FALSE |

Why is that?

Comment: Cannot replicate the issue on Oracle 11.2.0.2.0 [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/YD6K2XqH). Please [edit] the question and include details of your NLS settings (i.e. `NLS_SORT`, `NLS_COMP`, etc. The fiddle has a query for getting that data).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your profile says you are in France.

Given the setup:

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_LANGUAGE = 'French';
CREATE TABLE samuel(id varchar(1), field varchar(1));
INSERT INTO samuel VALUES ('1', ' ');
INSERT INTO samuel VALUES ('2', '&');
```

Then the default NLS settings for that language:

```sql
SELECT * FROM NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS;
```

Include:

| PARAMETER | VALUE |
| --- | --- |
| NLS_LANGUAGE | FRENCH |
| NLS_SORT | FRENCH |
| NLS_COMP | BINARY |

Then:

```sql
SELECT id, field FROM samuel order by field;
```

Outputs:

| ID | FIELD |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | & |
| 1 |  |

If you force the sort order to be binary:

```
SELECT id, field FROM samuel order by NLSSORT(field, 'NLS_SORT=BINARY');
```

Then the output is:

| ID | FIELD |
| --- | --- |
| 1 |  |
| 2 | & |

You need to make sure that you are sorting based on the rules you require. If necessary, you can use:

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_SORT='BINARY';
```

*(However, that would then use binary sorting for all queries in that session; not just this one query.)*

Then:

```
SELECT id, field FROM samuel order by field;
```

Outputs:

| ID | FIELD |
| --- | --- |
| 1 |  |
| 2 | & |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/mymEKVub)